What is the meaning of this sentence"やってやったぜというか、やってしまったぜ"?
Can someone translate this sentence?And what's different between "やってやった" and "やってしまった"? Thanks!
"やってやったぜというか、やってしまったぜ、かもしれないけど"

-てやった suggests that you're proud or satisfied with the result. See: What does てやる mean when it is not used for giving?
On the other hand, -てしまった indicates you're regretful or apologetic about the result.

やってやったぜというか、やってしまったぜ、かもしれないけど。
Hey I did it! ...Or perhaps it's more like "I ended up doing it", though.

